Server 2022 WSUS Install CreateDefaultSubscription
Recently did an install of Windows Server 2022. Trying to install WSUS with connection to our SQL Sever. I am able to install the features without the problem. The issue stems to my post installation. It fails with the following error:
CreatedDefaultSubscription failed. Exception: System.Net.Webexception: The request failed with the error message:
--.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[], parameters)
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.ApiRemoting.GetServerVersion()
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.DatabaseAccess.AdminDataAccessProxy.GetServerVersion()
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.UpdateServer.CreateUpdateServer(String serveName, Boolean, useSecureConnection, Int32 portNumber)
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.BaseApi.UpdatServer.ctor(Boolean bypassApiRemoting)
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Setup.StartServer.StartServer.CreateDefaultSubscription()

I need to get this installed to get my systems patched as this is an offline system. I can't tell what it is getting stuck on. I have removed the Application Pool and the WSUS Administration website over and over again and it keeps getting stuck on this spot.
